# Insert raw html code to quill

Tags: quill

Is there option to insert raw html code to quill?

```
quill.insertText();
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML()
```

both are parsed by matcher but I need to paste exactly formatted html code for an email footer.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/57002748/104380

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the footer content is meant to be static and un-editable, you can do this by [extending](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#extension) the BlockEmbed blot then adding a button for your new format in the toolbar. There are 2 different ways to handle what HTML get's entered into the new format.

### 1. Let the user enter the HTML to embed:

```js
// Import the BlockEmbed blot.
var BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

// Create a new format based off the BlockEmbed.
class Footer extends BlockEmbed {

    // Handle the creation of the new Footer format.
    // The value will be the HTML that is embedded.
    // By default, the toolbar will show a prompt window to get the value.
    static create(value) {

        // Create the node using the BlockEmbed's create method.
        var node = super.create(value);

        // Set the srcdoc attribute to equal the value which will be your html.
        node.setAttribute('srcdoc', value);

        // Add a few other iframe fixes.
        node.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
        node.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', true);
        node.setAttribute('width', '100%');
        return node;
    }

    // return the srcdoc attribute to represent the Footer's value in quill.
    static value(node) {
        return node.getAttribute('srcdoc');
    }

}

// Give our new Footer format a name to use in the toolbar.
Footer.blotName = 'footer';

// Give it a class name to edit the css.
Footer.className = 'ql-footer';

// Give it a tagName of iframe to tell quill what kind of element to create.
Footer.tagName = 'iframe';

// Lastly, register the new Footer format so we can use it in our editor.
Quill.register(Footer, true);

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            container: ['footer'] // Toolbar with just our footer tool (of course you can add all you want).
        }
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

```css
.ql-toolbar .ql-footer:before {
  content: 'footer';
}
.ql-editor .ql-footer {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="editor-container">
  <h1>Test Content</h1>
  <p>Enter a footer</p>
</div>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.min.js"></script>
```

### 2. Use specific HTML

```js
// Import the BlockEmbed blot.
var BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

// Create a new format based off the BlockEmbed.
class Footer extends BlockEmbed {

    // Handle the creation of the new Footer format.
    // The value will be the HTML that is embedded.
    // This time the value is passed from our custom handler.
    static create(value) {

        // Create the node using the BlockEmbed's create method.
        var node = super.create(value);

        // Set the srcdoc attribute to equal the value which will be your html.
        node.setAttribute('srcdoc', value);

        // Add a few other iframe fixes.
        node.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
        node.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', true);
        node.setAttribute('width', '100%');
        return node;
    }

    // return the srcdoc attribute to represent the Footer's value in quill.
    static value(node) {
        return node.getAttribute('srcdoc');
    }

}

// Give our new Footer format a name to use in the toolbar.
Footer.blotName = 'footer';

// Give it a class name to edit the css.
Footer.className = 'ql-footer';

// Give it a tagName of iframe to tell quill what kind of element to create.
Footer.tagName = 'iframe';

// Register the new Footer format so we can use it in our editor.
Quill.register(Footer, true);

// Specify the HTML that will be embedded.
var footerHTML = '<h1>Footer</h1>'
    + '<p>This is our new footer</p>';

// Create the footer handler.
var footerHandler = function() {

    // Get the cursor location to know where footer will be added.
    var index = this.quill.getSelection(true).index;

    // Insert the footer with the footerHTML.
    this.quill.insertEmbed(index, 'footer', footerHTML);
};

// Import the Toolbar module so we can add a custom handler to our footer button.
var Toolbar = Quill.import('modules/toolbar');

// Add our custom footer handler to the footer button.
Toolbar.DEFAULTS.handlers['footer'] = footerHandler;

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            container: ['footer'] // Toolbar with just our footer tool (of course you can add all you want).
        }
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

```css
.ql-toolbar .ql-footer:before {
  content: 'footer';
}
.ql-editor .ql-footer {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="editor-container">
  <h1>Test Content</h1>
  <p>Enter a footer</p>
</div>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So far this is the best solution. Unfortunately this is not an ideal solution. I have to search some more for a way to add text with option to edit it.

Comment: I was able to accomplish the editing and even resizing of custom embedded code for another project. I'll look it up and share later tonight.

Comment: Is there a way to paste raw html without `iframe`?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh, the iframe is needed for Quill's document model. It uses an object with properties and values to keep track of what is in the editor and make changes. If you add custom HTML that isn't tracked properly in Quill's document model, it will break.