# insert HTML with style into a QuillJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

How to insert html with style (css) to quillJS.
I have html like:

```
var data = '<p style="color: #f00">tesst</p>';
```

or

```
var data = '<style> .pp { color: #0f0;} </style>
<p class="pp">tesst</p>';
```

i paste it by

```
quill_arr[$('#docbody').attr('quill-id')].clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(data);
```

text load but format is:

```
<p>tesst</p>
```

without all styles. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846200/4051471

Comment: @shrys this is not the solution for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting a `<span>` with the styles inside a `<p>` seemed to work.

```
var data = '<p><span style="color: red;">test</span></p>'
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(data);
```

Checkout this

```html
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor"></div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Quill editor
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  
  // Insert HTML with style
  var data = '<p><span style="color: red;">Hello World!</span></p>'
  quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(data);
</script>
```

Comment: I used another editor for this, 
but this solution is great thanks

Comment: @Kaker which editor did you use? I am trying to accomplish inserting button with user preferred button name and button link.